# I need simple software for videos editing and merging?

Tags: video-editing

Main use is merging a bunch of video into one big ones.

Another use is clipping the videos. Cutting some part.

Simple ones are good.

Preferably open source free but that's not mandatory.

If paid, I prefer developers that have enough common sense to sell cheaper to Indonesian.

I tried openshot. They do not support simple merging. The resulting video is too big and choppy. I saw someone do it with avidemux and I will give it a try.

For simple videos merging I need something really simple. Something that can combine 2 videos in minutes. For something a bit more complex I need something that supports hardware encoding.

Comment: What OS? iMovie is free & built-in on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirements, I recommend using [OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org), or try something like [Avidemux](https://sourceforge.net/projects/avidemux/)

You can find a full comparison list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_editing_software).

Comment: I tried openshot. They do not support simple merging. The resulting video is too big and choppy.

Comment: Another tool use can use but it is command line is: http://ffmpeg.org/ It enables you to cut trim as follows e.g. ffmpeg -ss start_time -i inputVideo.mp4 -to end_time -c:v copy -c:a copy outputVideo.mp4  Please check documentation for flags usage

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to need is not a video "editor" per se, but a simpler tool for trimming and merging. A very important (in fact, crucial) feature of such tools is that they can usually do *lossless* editing without re-encoding the video.<sup>1</sup> Apart from preserving the quality, it is orders of magnitude quicker, practically instant to save.

The one I use is [SolveigMM Video Splitter](https://www.solveigmm.com/en/products/video-splitter/). Unlike some other similar tools I tried, it has a decent GUI and is the least destructive (e.g. preserves most metadata in files).

It is not free though. It has a free time-limited trial. They don't (I believe) sell cheaper to Indonesians, but they do to Russians (being a Russian company).

> Hint: just switch the website to the Russian language and you'll get a much (~4x) lower price.

---

<sup>1</sup> This usually entails some limitations, e.g. the first frame of a chunk must be the keyframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Write-on Video. It is an intuitive timeline-based video editor. Can crop, cut merge videos. Kdenlive is the another software for video editing. It's free and open-source. It works in GNU/Linux, Windows and BSD.

Comment: Hi Connor! Can you add links to your recommendations?

Comment: This is the [link](https://www.kdanmobile.com/writeon-video)

Comment: Thanks Connor.  The best way to add a link is directly within your answer.  Also, if you have links to both of your recommendations to add to your content, that would be great.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have written a tool for Linux that merges video files on base of ffmpeg. The original code is presented [here](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoMerge)

Videomerge tries **not** to encode the videos, thus makes it really fast. If you have different codecs to merge, reencoding must take place, thus taking more time and processing power.

In case you are using Debian,Ubuntu or Linux Mint you could install it via my ppa:

> [https://launchpad.net/~jentiger-moratai/+archive/ubuntu/mediatools](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejentiger-moratai/+archive/ubuntu/mediatools)

As an Arch Linux or Manjaro user "Videomerge" is provided in its AUR repository

As windows user, you might install "Anaconda" and ffmpeg, within that environment Videomerge will run.

> https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/videomerge

Videomerge is an app written by me as free & open-source code.

Comment: The answers here should be complete, not requiring clicking of links.  If your tool is just a script then you should post it here.

Comment: Ok - but the first answer contains only links themselves. So I do not understand the difference.