# Please recommend me a software to merge 2 mkv files using simple merge

Tags: file-merging, mkv

Basically I have 2 mkv files.

One is 30 minutes and another is 3 hours.

I want to simple merge those 2 mkv files.

I need a software for that.

It's a video format btw

I think I found it before but I forget

Similar with this question but for mkv

[I need simple software for videos editing and merging?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/78765/i-need-simple-software-for-videos-editing-and-merging)

No answer to that yet.

The software should run on windows 10. However, the more the better

Comment: Could you please **[edit]** your question and include what OS the software must run on, and what your price limit is when it comes to paid software? Also, should it be "minimalistic software" just for this task – or would "full video editors" be a welcome recommendation, too, as long as they cover your mentioned need?

Answer (score 2):

You can try Kdenlive. From their site:

> Multi-track video editing
>  Kdenlive allows you to use and arrange several audio and video tracks, each one can be locked or muted to your convenience.

[Kdenlive | Libre Video Editor](https://kdenlive.org/en/download)

[Wikipedia link](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdenlive)

[image: Kdenlive screenshot]

I couldn't understand what you mean by "simple merge" but you can use command line tools like FFMpeg.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org)

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mkv
```

Put path to your MKVs in mylist.txt in line seperated manner. You don't even need to think about re-encoding. The codecs will be copied as-is. Quality unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

[avidemux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avidemux) can add .mkv files at the end of each other.

Usage: Open the avidemux GUI, drag-and-drop the first .mkv file, then the second, then press "save" and enter the filename you want for the output file.

The input files must have the same size and encoding.

Available for Linux, Mac, Windows.

It is free and open source. It uses ffmpeg's libavcodec library under the hood.

Comment: Avidemux and Virtualdub are the best as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

https://www.fosshub.com/MKVToolNix.html

You can see the result here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_TCmWRUQrI

Basically a 3:20 video is combined with a 30 minutes video

Notice to do this you need to ensure you that you append video to another video

The first time I am doing it I just combine 2 video. The result is one mkv files that contain 2 chapters.

No I want to append one video one after another.

[https://www.macworld.com/article/223409/how-to-combine-two-dvds-into-a-single-movie.html#:~:text=Launch%20MKVToolNix%20and%20in%20the,navigate%20to%20the%20second%20movie](https://www.macworld.com/article/223409/how-to-combine-two-dvds-into-a-single-movie.html#:%7E:text=Launch%20MKVToolNix%20and%20in%20the,navigate%20to%20the%20second%20movie).

> Launch MKVToolNix and in the window that appears, drag your first
> movie file into the Input Files area (or click the Add button,
> navigate to the file, and then add it). Then click the Append button
> and navigate to the second movie.

That is how. Do not simply add 2 videos.